# How to refresh chartView after changing the data

Tags: android

Currently having problem while using AnyChart api to generate pie chart. The problem that i facing is it able to generate pie chart while on the first time however after select on spinner the chartView become empty. I have tried to use debug mode to check the progress after select from spinner however it is running successfully even the data is passing correctly. So, i was thinking maybe what i need to do is just to refresh the chartView. But, i have tried refreshDrawableState(), notfiy() and invalidate() still can't refresh the chartView.

AnyChart resource: https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android#pie-chart

While running on the first time

[image]

After select from spinner

[image]

Here is my coding

```
dateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                     String tempDate = dateSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                     UserFoodRecord tempRecord = null;
                     if (trackList!= null) {
                         for (UserFoodRecord u : trackList) {
                             if (u.date.equals(tempDate)){
                                 tempRecord = u;
                             }
                         }
                     }

                     if (tempRecord != null){
                         breakfast = tempRecord.getBreakfast();
                         lunch = tempRecord.getLunch();
                         dinner = tempRecord.getDinner();
                         other = tempRecord.getOther();

                         if (breakfast != null){
                             for (com.example.cheejin.fyp.FoodInfo.Item item : breakfast){
                                 quantity = item.getQuantity();

                                 calories += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCalories())*quantity;
                                 carbs += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCarbs())*quantity;
                                 protein += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getProtein())*quantity;
                                 fats += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getFat())*quantity;
                             }
                         }

                         if (lunch != null){
                             for (com.example.cheejin.fyp.FoodInfo.Item item : lunch){
                                 calories += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCalories())*quantity;
                                 carbs += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCarbs())*quantity;
                                 protein += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getProtein())*quantity;
                                 fats += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getFat())*quantity;
                             }
                         }

                         if (dinner != null){
                             for (com.example.cheejin.fyp.FoodInfo.Item item : dinner){
                                 calories += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCalories())*quantity;
                                 carbs += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCarbs())*quantity;
                                 protein += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getProtein())*quantity;
                                 fats += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getFat())*quantity;
                             }
                         }

                         if (other != null){
                             for (com.example.cheejin.fyp.FoodInfo.Item item : other){
                                 calories += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCalories())*quantity;
                                 carbs += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getCarbs())*quantity;
                                 protein += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getProtein())*quantity;
                                 fats += Double.parseDouble(item.getNutrient().getFat())*quantity;
                             }
                         }
                         List<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
                         data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Calories", 200));
                         data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Carbs", 50));
                         data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Proteins", 180));
                         data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Fats", 50));
                         Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
                         pie.setData(data);
                         anyChartView.setChart(pie);
                         anyChartView.refreshDrawableState();
                     }
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                 }

             });
```

Answer (score 2):

I am responding to this topic a long time after but because  I have faced the same problem and I finally found the solution to the problem.

What you need to do, is to create a private Pie property in your activity or fragment class like this  :

```
lateinit var pie: Pie
```

then in your onCreateView or instance depending if you're on an activity or fragment set your `Pie` property to your AnyChartView like this :

```
pie = AnyChart.pie()
val anyChartView = root.findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view) as AnyChartView
anyChartView.setChart(pie)
```

Then in your spinner `onItemSelected` event you just need to update your `pie` data like this :

```
pie.data(data)
```

and this will automaticly update your chart, you don't need to do`anyChartView.setChart(pie)` everytime your event is fired it's not gonna work

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the method `invalidate()` on Pie object after `setData(Data)`.

The code should be like this:

```
pie.setData(data);
pie.invalidate();
```

This works for me.

Comment: Unable to add invalidate for pie, because dont have this function but can add to anyChartView.